# Data migration issue : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation from maento 1.9 to magento 2.4.1

Tags: product-images, media-images, data-migration-tool, magento2.4.1, magento1.9.0.1

I am migrating the data from Magento 1 to magento 2.4.1 by running the following command

> php bin/magento migrate:data --reset
> vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.0.1/config.xml

But it throws the following error and stopped migration

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '137-24' for key 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID'`

please refer to the attachment

[image]

Comment: Hey, backup the database, but I think you can truncate that table with no problem should be catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity or something similar, when I did the migration I truncated that table

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Add the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` table inside the ignore document section of both source and destination in `map.xml`, and then proceed migration it works like charm